# how should I compare Double value with Long.MAX_VALUE? and Long.MAX_VALUE+1d

Tags: java, comparison, double

I want to compare two double value as follow:

`Double doubleValue = Double.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE);`

`Double doubleValue2 = Double.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE+1d);`

Apparently doubleValue and doubleValu2 are not equal, 2nd is larger due to the 1d addition.

but no matter I use compare() or equals() method, both methods return a equal result for two values. Is there any way I can compare and not losing accuracy here.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Those two double values _are_ exactly equal, because doubles don't have enough precision to measure the difference.

Comment: I think you are using the word "apparently" incorrectly.  "Apparently XYZ" means that the XYZ appears to be true based on the available evidence.  I think you probably meant that you *expected* the the numbers to be the same, but *apparently* they are not the same.

Comment: I would avoid the use of `Double` when `double` would produce the same result as it adds complexity your example (and code in general) doesn't need.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of the loss of precision while converting long to double

```
    double d1 = (double)Long.MAX_VALUE;
    double d2 = Long.MAX_VALUE + 1.0;
    System.out.println(d1);
    System.out.println(d2);
```

it gives the same numbers

```
9.223372036854776E18
9.223372036854776E18
```

long has 32 bits and double's significand has 53 bits http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format. In decimal terms, max long = 9223372036854775807, it is 19 digits, and double can hold 17 max

Answer (score 1):

Long.MAX_VALUE has 63 significant bits. A double cannot exactly represent any number with more than 53 significant bits. If you want to do exact calculations with integers bigger than Long.MAX_VALUE I suggest using java.math.BigInteger.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger longMax = BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    BigInteger plusOne = longMax.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    System.out.println(longMax.equals(plusOne));
  }
}
```